# Rollback a changeset from the command-line only in TFS?

Tags: version-control, tfs

I'm building an automated promotion utility for TFS. One of the features I'd like to support is rolling back the latest change. I'm quite aware of the Rollback Power Tool, but my understanding is that even if you pass a changeset in through the command line, it still brings up the GUI interface for other operations.

My thought is to walk the changeset history of the branch I want to rollback, create a new workspace, get the specific version of the changeset before the last one, then merge it to the current workspace, forcing conflicts to be resolved from the previous version. This all runs on a server in an automated fashion and the workspaces are created and deleted on the fly.

Any other suggestions for a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the /noprompt option to stop the rollback powertool popping up a GUI and also /automerge if you're feeling brave enough.